# How to align the note with the left side of the figure?

Tags: alignment, figure

I am trying to put notes in the pictures of my work but the notes are getting aligned with the border of the text and not the figure. How to align the note (Fonte: Elaborated by the author (2021)) of the table with the left side of the figure?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=.35]{image.jpg}  
        \caption{Text tex text.}
        \label{fig_intbus}
    \end{center}
\fonte{Elaborated by the author (2021)..}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

I would like something similar to the `threeparttable` environment for tables but that can be used in figures. I thought about the `minipage` environment but I don't want to specify the width for each figure manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it, defining a new caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\fonte}[1]{\captionsetup{skip=0.5ex,position=b}\caption*{\textit{Fonte:} {#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example image.}
\label{fig-img-a}
\fonte{Teste.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image: example result]